# ui-select-choices object (hashtable) instead of array of objects

Tags: angularjs, hashtable, ui-select, angular-ui-select

I have the following `ui-select` working:

```
<ui-select ng-model="vm.example" name="example">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select...">{{$select.selected.key}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="x in vm.examples | filter: $select.search">
            <div ng-bind-html="x.key | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

And the source for this select is the following array...

```
vm.examples = [
    {key:'a', value: 1},
    {key:'b', value: 2},
    {key:'c', value: 3}
]
```

However, I want my "datasource" for the select to be an object literal, as it follows...

```
vm.examples = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
}
```

I have tried several times and couldn't be able to make it work, any ideas? If it is not possible due to the `ui-select` current implementation... somebody knows the reason??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found an answer in the `ui-select` wiki on [GitHub](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select-choices#user-content-example-iterating-over-objects)!

```
<ui-select ng-model="person.selectedValue" title="Choose a person">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a person in the list or search his name/age...">{{$select.selected.value.name}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="person.value as (key, person) in peopleObj | filter: {'value':$select.search}">
    <div ng-bind-html="person.value.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    <small>
      email: {{person.value.email}}
      age: <span ng-bind-html="''+person.value.age | highlight: $select.search"></span>
    </small>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```